# Windows 7 need an easy way to track file changes and restore to previous versions

Tags: windows, version-control

I am looking for some way to roll back file changes. I have looked at versioning systems such as tortoiseCVS, but I can't seem to get it setup.

If anyone can help me find a great solution to track and roll back file changes on win7 that would be great!

Chris

Comment: Versioning is **the** answer. CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial... it really doesn't matter which one, as long as it works for you (and it's **not** VSS). If you want to stick with CVS, ask a question on [SU](http://superuser.com) about troubleshooting the TortoiseCVS install.

Comment: Windows 7 comes with its "Restore Previous Versions" facility. It's like a versioned recycle bin. If you want a version control system (VCS) then persevere.

Comment: @Matt you mean "and it's **not** VSS"

Comment: @David: `head->desk` yes, thank you

Comment: @Matt It's astounding quite how bad VSS is. With most VCS you put your files in to it with the expectation that they will be kept safe. Putting your files into VSS is like piping them to /dev/nul!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very easy solution is to use DropBox.  It uses SVN under the hood, but you don't have to do anything, or even be aware of that fact.  All the files in your dropbox folder are automatically versioned.  Now, DropBox also lets you share files, and replicates them to the web, but you don't have to use these features at all.

The main limitation is that the free account is limited to 2 GB.